# How to force playing attack animation until the end?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I rework the code to make it more easier to manage. How can I force the player cannot change the sprite animation by pressing any keys until the attack animation completely ends?

```
class Player
{
    Animation playerIdle;
    Animation playerRun;
    Animation playerAtk;    

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        playerIdle = new Animation(content, "idle", 144, 128, 8, 30);
        playerRun = new Animation(content, "run", 160, 112, 8, 30);
        playerAtk = new Animation(content, "atk", 154, 131, 2, 30);

        playerIdle.EnableRepeating();
        playerRun.EnableRepeating();
        playerAtk.EnableRepeating();
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        playerIdle.Update(gameTime);
        UpdateControl(gameTime);
    }

    #region Update Control
    string selectSpriteSheet;

    KeyboardState mPreviousKeyboardState;
    SpriteEffects spriteEffects = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;

    Vector2 feetPosition = new Vector2(0, 350);
    Vector2 mSpeed = Vector2.Zero;
    Vector2 mDirection = Vector2.Zero;
    Vector2 mStartingPosition = Vector2.Zero;

    int CHARACTER_SPEED = 50;
    int MOVE_LEFT = -5;
    int MOVE_RIGHT = 5;
    int MOVE_UP = -5;
    int MOVE_DOWN = 5;


    enum State
    {
        Running,
        Jumping,
        Attacking,
    }

    State mCurrentState = State.Running;

    public void UpdateControl(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        feetPosition += mDirection * mSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        selectSpriteSheet = "idle";
        UpdateMovement(aCurrentKeyboardState, gameTime);
        //UpdateJump(aCurrentKeyboardState, gameTime);

        mPreviousKeyboardState = aCurrentKeyboardState;
    }

    private void UpdateMovement(KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (mCurrentState == State.Running)
        {
            mSpeed = Vector2.Zero;
            mDirection = Vector2.Zero;

            if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && !aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                playerRun.Update(gameTime);

                selectSpriteSheet = "run";
                spriteEffects = SpriteEffects.None;
                mSpeed.X = CHARACTER_SPEED;
                mDirection.X = MOVE_LEFT;


            }
            else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && !aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                playerRun.Update(gameTime);

                selectSpriteSheet = "run";
                spriteEffects = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
                mSpeed.X = CHARACTER_SPEED;
                mDirection.X = MOVE_RIGHT;
            }

            if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z) && mPreviousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Z))
            {
                mCurrentState = State.Attacking;
            }
        }

        if (mCurrentState == State.Attacking)
        {
            playerAtk.Update(gameTime);

            selectSpriteSheet = "hit";
            mCurrentState = State.Running;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        //playerIdle.Draw(spriteBatch, feetPosition, (float)MathHelper.ToRadians(0), 1.0f);
        if (selectSpriteSheet == "idle")
            playerIdle.Draw(spriteBatch, feetPosition, spriteEffects, (float)MathHelper.ToRadians(0),1.0f);
        else if (selectSpriteSheet == "run")
            playerRun.Draw(spriteBatch, feetPosition, spriteEffects, (float)MathHelper.ToRadians(0),1.0f);
        else if (selectSpriteSheet == "hit")
            playerAtk.Draw(spriteBatch, feetPosition, spriteEffects, (float)MathHelper.ToRadians(0), 1.0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The player class should have a `currentAnimation` and a `nextAnimation`.

If the `currentAnimation` is flagged as `uninterruptible`, then any attempts to change `newAnimation` are applied to `nextAnimation` and the `currentAnimation` is set to not repeat. Then, when the `currentAnimation` ends, `nextAnimation` will take its place.

Comment: currentAnimation is flagged as uninterruptible? How to do the flag? Sorry but I am a beginner.

Comment: Make a boolean in your animation class. Make it `true` for the animations that are uninterruptible.